# Авторизоваться на нескольких одинаковых сайтах

Tags: javascript, apache, google-chrome

Дело в том что есть несколько сайтов на бекенде и есть операторы которые переходят между сайтами для того чтобы консультировать людей по их заказам.

Идея в том чтобы сделать расширение для браузера chrome которое будет автоматически авторизовываться на необходимых сайтах.

Конкретно сейчас затуп в том что не могу понять как передать серверу что я тот самый авторизованный человек, у коготорого есть headers - Authorization: Basic ***

Подскажите в каком направлении дуть? :(

Answer (score 0):

Вам потребуется как-то передавать данные сессии с одного сайта на другой. Например: после авторизации на первом сайте, все переменные сессии записываются в базу данных и еще уникальный маркер с ограниченным временем действия (MD5). Теперь все ссылки ведущие с одного сайта на другой, должны содержать этот маркер. При переходе на другой сайт, открывается новая сессия, маркер отлавливается и по нему из базы данных подтягиваются все переменные сессии. Проблема здесь только одна, пользователь должен гулять с одного сайта на другой только по ссылкам, иначе маркер потеряется. При каждом запросе время действия маркера продлевается.

Но есть вариант более продвинутый. Вообще убрать обычную авторизацию по сессиям. Всем пользователям каким-то способом раздавать дочерние SSL-сертификаты (можно с ограниченным временем действия) привязанные к обещему мультидоменному сертификату ваших сайтов, а ваш сертификат к какому-нибудь корневому сертификат-авторити. Когда пользователь приходит на любой из ваших сайтов, достаточно проверить валидность его сертификата и все!